# Statically linking a library

Tags: linker, makefile, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a library say libX.a I am creating one more library myLib2.a i want to statically link libX.a with myLib2.a 
The problem is when i use myLib2.a it complaints asking for libX.a but i want libX.a to be part of myLib2.a so that I can directly use myLib2.a

I have already tried to generate myLib2.a and was successful in doing so but when I try to use it i get error.
Can you please suggest is this is possible? and if possible how can we achieve this using a makefile.

Thanks and regards,

Rohit

Comment: Do you mean that you want to combine the two libraries to form one library? Or that you want to link the two libraries (and maybe other objects) to form an executable? Does `myLib2.a` use elements of `libX.a`?

Comment: I want to link the two libraries to make one library.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to link the two libraries to make one library.

You don't want to *link* the two libraries; you want to *combine* them. A recipe is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662430/combining-several-static-archives-into-a-new-one).

Answer (score 0):

Extract the object files from `libX.a` (using `ar -x`), then add them to `myLib2.a` (using `ar -r`).

In a makefile:

```
CONTENTS := $(filter %.o,$(shell ar -t libX.a))

libMy2.a: libX.a
    ar -x libX.a
    ar -r $@ $(CONTENTS)
    rm $(CONTENTS)
```