# cmake: how to add all the symbols of a dependent static library into a static library being built

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, undefined-symbol

I work on a C++ project where I create a static library (let's call it target1).
This library depends on 2 other libraries (let's call them dep1 and dep2).
The project uses cmake to build target1.
Once it is built, if I run `nm -C libtarget1.a | c++filt` and grep for the symbols in dep1 or dep2, they are present but all undefined.
Consequently, users of libtarget1.a gets undefined references at link time. Not useful at all; we want target1 to be complete and independent (wrt dep1 and dep2).

So my question is: How do I tell cmake to add all the symbols from dep1 and dep2 into target1?

Here is what I tried and do not work:

- This answer [Combining several static libraries into one using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake) did not make it work: The symbols from dep1 and dep2 were still all undefined.
- `target_link_libraries()` with various combinations of `-Wl,--whole-archive` and `-Wl,--no-whole-archive`.
- `target_link_libraries()` with various combinations of `PUBLIC, LINK_PUBLIC, INTERFACE, LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES`.
- Using `add_custom_target()`.

Here is something that works (outside cmake though) with flaws:

```
ar -M <<EOM
    CREATE libtarget1all.a
    ADDLIB libtarget1.a
    ADDLIB libdep1.a
    ADDLIB libdep2.a
    SAVE
    END
EOM
```

The flaw is that libtarget1all.a contains the symbols from dep1 and dep2 indeed but both as defined and undefined at the same time...

Comment: `do I tell cmake to add all the symbols from dep1 and dep2 into target1?` this is unrelated to cmake, this is just how linker works.

Comment: Linking static libraries together for obtain a single library which has definition for all functions (and other symbols) is not the task supported by CMake out-of-the-box. Howerer, using a custom command or custom target with proper command line you may achieve that. See [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake) for more details.