# CMake: how to package ALL dependencies into a static library?

Tags: c, cmake, linker, static-libraries

Related: [Combining several static libraries into one using CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37924383)

When we use CMake to build a library `add_library(example STATIC lib.c)`, we will get a `libexample.a` file. If we have the following dependency: `target_link_libraries(example PUBLIC lib123)` where `lib123` is another library, then we must have `libx` installed on a computer to use `libexample.a`. Otherwise, if we do `gcc main.c libexample.a` the compiler will not be able to find symbols in `lib123` required by functions in `libexample.a`.

The link above mentions how to merge these libraries manually. But when merging `lib123`,  we realise that `lib123` have a lot of other dependencies.

How to automatically resolve all dependencies and merge all of them to `libexample.a`?

Comment: "How to automatically resolve all dependencies" - Unlike to a *shared* library, a **static** library doesn't have dependency list embedded to it. You need to read list of static library dependencies from *somewhere* (e.g. from `pkg-config`) and pass that list to the merge tool.