# CMake target_link_libraries doesn't include symbols

Tags: c++, cmake, static-linking

I'm trying to create a static library and link to it a symbol from another static library, which is used by it. Although I pass to [target_link_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) necessary lib, the symbol is not included. See the small example below:

This is my `library.cpp`:

```
#include <mysql.h>

void fun() {
  MYSQL* x;
  mysql_errno(x);
}
```

And this is `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
add_library(mylib library.cpp)
target_include_directories(mylib /usr/include/mysql)
target_link_libraries(mylib PUBLIC /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a)
```

After running `cmake .. && make`, the library libmylib.a is created, but it doesn't contain `mysql_errno` symbol:

```
arrno@zzz1-msi:~$ cmake .. && make
Scanning dependencies of target mylib
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/library.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libmylib.a

arrno@zzz1-msi:~$ nm libmylib.a

library.o:
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U mysql_errno
0000000000000000 T _Z3funv
```

In libmysqlclient.a the symbol `mysql_errno` is defined:

```
arrno@zzz1-msi:~$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.a | grep mysql_errno
0000000000000000 T mysql_errno
```

I want to use `libmylib.a` in my programs without linking `libmysqlclient.a`. Now I cannot. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Creation of a **static** library doesn't involve a linking step, so your `mylib` library contains only symbols defined in its sources. For merge a static library into other static library, see the [duplicate question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake).