How can I statically link system libraries into a static library using cmake
I'm working on a fairly substantial application and need to provide part of the functionality to other teams in the company as a static library (the main reason for the static library is to prevent conflicts with potential different versions of sub-libraries or different compiler versions/options).
I can statically link sub-libraries into my library by using the $<TARGET_OBJECTS:subLibName> syntax, as in example, below:
add_library(
   MyLibrary STATIC
        ${MyLibrarySourceFiles}
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:SubLib1>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:SubLib2>
)

But I'm at a total loss on how to include external libraries like e.g. crypt32 or libucrt.lib.
I'ld prefer to only provide a release version of the library as it makes deployment a bit easier (in my current attempts, I can't compile a debug version of a test application using MyLibrary because of a release/debug conflict between the VS runtime in the library and the application which I hope would be solved by linking MyLibrary against libucrt.lib).

I suspect you're on Windows? I'd really wonder if you could find any static system library. Please, note that an SDK may provide .lib files which provide entry points for .dlls. Nevertheless, this is still dynamically linking. Static libraries are actually archives of objects (.obj). I.e. they cannot be linked to each other - they have to be linked into an executable (or a .dll). At best, you can unpack a .lib and add the resulting object files into another .lib.

You can certainly add_custom_target in CMake to call ar on Linux, libtool on MacOS or lib.exe on Windows to merge libraries together ... but it is not that common need so I'm not sure if there is some better option

Or use the dual approach, export a static lib and accept transitive dependencies exist. And/or still deploy a dll (in a different package). And make sure that dll doesn't expose any of the types of the other libraries at all (ideally expose a factory method that returns an abstract interface to your library, thus hiding ALL the implementation details). IMO having one "static library" isn't really a must unless there is some kind of explicit memory/diskspace requirement.

Here is a question about combining static libraries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake

Is your library a DLL?

What you are trying to do doesn't make a lot of sense for more reasons than one. Here's one: imagine there is another library vendor that produces an entirely different library, but they do the same as you — and include different versions of all the system libraries. How do you use both products together?

@n.m.couldbeanAI Since my library has a C interface and doesn't expose the libraries it's linked to that shouldn't be a problem I guess.

In light of the info provided here, I'll provide my library in a debug and release version and it will be up to the users of the library to link against crypt32 and the VS runtime library. Thanks for your insights.

"doesn't expose the libraries it's linked to" A static library cannot do that. It is not linked to anything, it is a dumb collection of objects, and everything in these objects is exposed.

I don't use CMAKE, but I can at least provide some info.  There's a difference between crypt32 and libucrt.lib, so you need to handle them differently.
crypt32.dll is a Windows DLL - you'll find it in c:\windows\system32 - so you don't need to worry about it, the consumers of your library will already have it.
libucrt.lib is the C++ runtime and is supplied with the compiler, and there are two versions - static and dynamic.  Each of these comes in two further versions, Debug and Release.
It's unfortunate, but MSVC mandates that you impose the constraint on the consumers of your library (or maybe they impose it on you) that you both build with the same flavour of runtime - static Release, say.  Everything should then 'just work'.
I would add (if I understand you right) that I find it strange that the team developing the application don't (also) want you to supply a Debug build of your library, then they can build their app that way too.  Debugging Release code can be a nightmare.

Since the consumers of the library don't need to debug the library I was hoping I would be able to only supply a release version that they could use in both the debug and release version of their application (this works on macOS).

You can try it, but at best it's likely to be brittle because some containers are implemented differently in Debug and Release builds (the Debug versions have bounds checking and suchlike) and therefore have different memory layouts.  Personally, I wouldn't.
