How does CMake link a static library to another?
I'm trying to learn CMake and i struggle to understand the concept of transitive linking of static libraries.
Let's image the following basic scenario:
add_library(utils STATIC utils.cpp)

add_library(client STATIC client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(client utils)

add_executable(client_cli main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(client_cli client)

My questions are:

Will this create 2 separate static libraries, both of which need to be linked to client_cli in the final linking step? Or will it integrate the content of the lib utils (utils.cpp) into the lib client and produce one library with everything?
Is there a way to override the default behaviour and make it do it the other way around?


This is not really about cmake.  When you create a static library, the linker never tries to "satisfy" the externals it references.  It's just a collection of object modules.  If static library xxx.a needs things in static library yyy.a, then users of xxx.a will also need to bring in yyy.a.

"Will this create 2 separate static libraries, both of which need to be linked to client_cli in the final linking step?" - That. CMake doesn't provide a cross-platform way for merge static libraries into the single one. You need to use manually prepared command for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake
